# Can't set tag or commit as branch/version when create git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying specify git submodule branch to tag:

```
git submodule add --branch 8.0.0.2 -f \
              git@git.TEST.com:tbicr/test_submodule.git src/test_submodule
```

or commit:

```
git submodule add --branch 5c0f8d23 -f \
              git@git.TEST.com:tbicr/test_submodule.git src/test_submodule
```

But I get next error:

```
Reactivating local git directory for submodule 'src/test_submodule'.
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch '8.0.0.2' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/8.0.0.2' which can not be resolved as commit?
Unable to checkout submodule 'src/test_submodule'
```

I see that it try checkout to **origin**/8.0.0.2 instead **tags**.

I even try `tags/8.0.0.2` and `refs/tags/8.0.0.2`, but it try checkout to `origin/tags/8.0.0.2` and `origin/refs/tags/8.0.0.2` in error message.

For `master` and other general branches all work fine.

I have next `test_submodule` refs:

```
refs/heads/master
refs/remotes/origin/8.0
refs/tags/8.0.0.2
refs/tags/8.0.0.3
```

git version 2.1.4

Can I specify submodule branch/version to tag or commit?